# Force GIMP treating pixels as linear values

Tags: gimp, color-profile

I have an image with no color profile information, that GIMP treats as sRGB, but actually is linear. Is it possible to switch to linear mode, *without* touch pixel values.

Comment: This is a dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/1725635/assign-linear-colorspace-to-tiff-image which at least contained more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "linear mode"?

Comment: I had a look at your other question, do you mean it's a greyscale image, but shows as RGB mode in GIMP? If so, can't you just change it using *Image > Mode > Greyscale*?

Comment: Also, just another thought, is the original TIFF image a scan?  If so, perhaps you should check to see if there is an actual greyscale output option in your scanner software - of course that's assuming you are the one doing the scanning.

Comment: @BillyKerr The original image has been constructed from the Cop30 data set, and fetched from OpenTopography.org.

Comment: Does changing to greyscale mode work for you?

Comment: @Billy Kerr. The image is grayscale, and the current mode is grayscale. Linear has nothing to do with color or grayscale. A linear image is an image where pixel values are proportional to the intensity. I must till GIMP that this image should be treated as linear, regardless of what the TIFF standard (or any metadata) says.

Comment: Do you mean converting to linear which is available under *Image > Precision > Linear Light*?  If you convert to linear light, you will also probably have to convert to 16bit precision first, otherwise you will get horrible posterization if you try to edit anything in this mode. The GIMP developers don't recommend editing in linear light at 8bits.

Comment: @Billy Kerr The problem is that any operation that changes mode also changes the pixel values. I expect the visual appearance to change. Note: The data is 32-bit float.